# Sending URL to Google Maps from PHP with latitude and longitude values

Tags: php, google-maps

I am new to PHP coding. A PHP file in my server is receiving from a mobile client latitude and longitude values in a GET request. A URL is then being constructed to send the data to Google Maps to be displayed. Below is the code:

```
$getdata = http_build_query(
array(
   'latitude' => $_GET["latitude"],
   'longitude'=> $_GET["longitude"],
)
);
$result=file_get_contents('http://maps.googlemaps.com/maps/geocode/json?'.$getdata)
```

Is this the right way to form the URL? Thank you in advance.

Comment: How should we know? We are not google! I suggest you take a look at their API documentation...

Comment: No I mean the PHP syntax.

Comment: Well that is syntactically valid, but does not make any sense. Just dump the url and see yourself. You have to `json_encode()` that stuff at least...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to get actual map web page, you need to for url as:

```
'http://maps.google.com/?q='.$getdata['latitude'].','.$getdata['longitude']
```

If you need to use geocoding services then:

```
'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$getdata['latitude'].','.$getdata['longitude'].'&sensor=false'
```

As your URL seem to be not functional. You'd better refer to the Google Maps API docs

Comment: Thank you. I need the geocoding services.